# Hosting help content online

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to package some of my MFC applications as Windows 10 apps using [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).

I am having no end of trouble getting my HTML help file (CHM) included and working with the installed program (new versions of VS don't include the help file, and using workaround to include that file results in a file that I don't have the rights to access).

So it makes me wonder about hosting the online help on my website. A couple of the issues that arise is how best to host multiple help topics, and how to override (on a application-wide basis) the behavior of accessing help topics. (My app is dialog-based.)

So I just wondered if anyone else has done this already. I'd be curious to review how these issues were addressed. I was not able to find anything online.

Comment: So what happens __exactly__ when you try to display a topic of the chm file?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I don't want to get too far into that as I've spent over a month trying to resolve various issues and I've been working with people within Microsoft. In short, if the CHM file doesn't get installed as part of the package, it can't open if it doesn't exist. And if the file is copied but you don't have rights to open the file, MFC gives a generic message about being unable to load the help file. I am continued to explore these many issues, but here I just want to talk about hosting the help content online.

Comment: I used a package (which I don't think is available anymore) to convert my CHM files to HTML. Example: http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa/HelpOnline/

Comment: Also https://www.helpndoc.com/

Answer (score 1):

I do host my html help in a single document, using html anchors to get to the topic of interest. If you have multiple pages, adapt MyHelp accordingly.

I didn't actually use the Desktop Bridge but wondered if you have tried something like this:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo) 
{
    MyHelp(_T("HIDD_MYDIALOG"));            // HTML anchor goes here
    return CDialog::OnHelpInfo(pHelpInfo);
}

...

// a global helper function for showing help
void MyHelp(LPCTSTR anchor)
{
    extern CMyApp theApp;
    TCHAR *cp, buffer[1000];

    // look for the html document in the program directory
    strcpy(buffer, _T("file:///"));
    DWORD dw = GetModuleFileName(theApp.m_hInstance, buffer + strlen(buffer), sizeof(buffer));

    if (cp = strrchr(buffer, '\\'))
    {
        strcpy(cp+1, _T("MyHelpDocument.htm#"));
        strcat(cp+1, anchor);

        // for some reason, I don't want the default browser to open, just the Internet Explorer
        ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("iexplore"), buffer, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            // or, for real online help, use just '_T("http://myurl.com/myonlinehelpdocument.html#") + anchor'
            // instead of 'buffer' and ommit all before ShellExecute()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if ShellExecute will behave the way it used to in the shop app though. But certainly there will be a way to open a URL somehow. You might want to try if the Internet Explorer ActiveX works to display your help pages inside the app.

Comment: So you had to insert code into every dialog box class in your application? Isn't there a common, underlying method that can be overridden?

Comment: Sure, you can catch WM_COMMANDHELP in the main message loop. But you have to map all your help context ids to urls in the handler. I think this is too centralized and the amount of work isn't really lower than having distinct OnHelpInfo() members. You could work on a compromise though, having a CHelpfulDialog derived from CDialog with the dialog id as base for your url, or CHelpfulWnd from CWnd, using the window title to generate a url. But again, you have to replace all CDialogs or CWnds with your derived classes, which is still some work.

Comment: That's exactly the type of centralization I would be looking for. I could either have that handler convert the topic ID to something else, or--more likely--have the website just handle the ID as an argument. I'll play with that.

Comment: However, I don't believe there is a single place to catch this message in a dialog-based application.